# Lifetime when exchanging reference

Tags: rust, reference, lifetime, mutable

I'm learning Rust and play through some scenarios to see how it behaves. When passing a mutable reference to a function and then assign another mutable reference to it, it seems like the Rust compiler wants the referenced variable to live as long as the one originally referenced.

However, as I am literally exchanging the reference to point somewhere else, it would never affect the reference of the calling function. It will always still point to foo, which is perfectly alive. Why does foo2 have to live as long as foo then? This seems like it expects something like replacing the reference in the original reference ...

```
struct Foo {
    x: u32,
    y: u32
}

fn do_something(mut foo: &mut Foo) {
    foo.x = 4;
    foo.y = 5;
    println!("foo.x = {}\nfoo.y = {}", foo.x, foo.y);
    let mut foo2 = Foo{x: 10, y: 20};
    foo = &mut foo2;
    println!("foo.x = {}\nfoo.y = {}", foo.x, foo.y);
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo{x: 1, y: 2};
    do_something(&mut foo);
    println!("foo.x = {}\nfoo.y = {}", foo.x, foo.y);
}
```

This is what the compiler says:

```
error[E0597]: `foo2` does not live long enough
  --> main.rs:11:11
   |
6  | fn do_something(mut foo: &mut Foo) {
   |                          - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
10 |     let mut foo2 = Foo{x: 10, y: 20};
   |         -------- binding `foo2` declared here
11 |     foo = &mut foo2;
   |     ------^^^^^^^^^
   |     |     |
   |     |     borrowed value does not live long enough
   |     assignment requires that `foo2` is borrowed for `'1`
12 |     println!("foo.x = {}\nfoo.y = {}", foo.x, foo.y);
13 | }
   | - `foo2` dropped here while still borrowed

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the *type* of `&mut Foo` includes a lifetime, and that lifetime is bigger than that of `foo2`. This is a problem, because you the compiler assumes that lifetime is big, and you can exploit that. For example:

```rust
fn do_something(mut foo: &mut Foo) -> &mut Foo {
    foo.x = 4;
    foo.y = 5;
    println!("foo.x = {}\nfoo.y = {}", foo.x, foo.y);
    let mut foo2 = Foo{x: 10, y: 20};
    foo = &mut foo2;
    println!("foo.x = {}\nfoo.y = {}", foo.x, foo.y);
    foo
}
```

Here, due to lifetime elision, the lifetime of the return type is the same as the lifetime of `foo`. But we return `foo`: this must be okay. However, this code is not okay: it clearly has a use-after-free. The only valid conclusion is that the assignment `foo = &mut foo2` is invalid.

If you declare a new variable, that its lifetime is shorter, it will work:

```rust
fn do_something(foo: &mut Foo) {
    let mut foo = foo;
    foo.x = 4;
    foo.y = 5;
    println!("foo.x = {}\nfoo.y = {}", foo.x, foo.y);
    let mut foo2 = Foo{x: 10, y: 20};
    foo = &mut foo2;
    println!("foo.x = {}\nfoo.y = {}", foo.x, foo.y);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So the problem is just in case you return the newly assigned mutable reference, which can't happen because foo2 goes out of scope while the type of foo has a lifetime that would indicate it is still valid? Couldn't the compiler just check if you return a reference with an invalid lifetime when it actually happens and allow the assignment otherwise?

Comment: @tweekz Returning is just an example. It could as well happen with nested reference (`&mut &mut Foo`). Could the compiler "fix" this? It probably could, like it can in case we declare a new variable. But it's not possible in case of nested references or just a type containing reference, so this would make the language inconsistent. And in general, the rule is that references' types contain lifetime, and the lifetime here is too big.